# How can I save user preference in messenger bot built by rasa

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, rasa-nlu

I have built a bot for facebook messenger using rasa nlu . Initially I am giving user a language select option. I want to save user preference at the first time and later , I do not want to ask user again to set their language preference , how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a seperate slot for your language and save it in that slot. Then your further developments can be done by looking at the language slot value.
Slot is like a placeholder in rasa.

In you domain.py file, you can define the slot like this

```
slots:
  language:
    type: text
    initial_value: "en"
```

Then you can define it as an entity in your same domain.py file like below.

```
entities: 
  - language
```

then you can set your slot value in your stories like below.

```
visitor_resp{"language":"english"}
```

And the your language slot value is set.

For more details please visit https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/slots/